# problemas procedure actualizar stock

Tags: java, mysql

he creado mi procedure en mi BD mysql, se pudo crear sin problemas. Es un procedure para registrar venta y actualizar el stock. Pero al querer registrar la venta en mi netbeans no se puede, me aparece un error. Me podrán orientar en indentificarlo y solucionarlo?. Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias.
[image: insertar]
[image: error venta]
[image: procedure]
[image: tabla operacion]
[image: tabla producto]

Comment: La variable `sSQL` espera ocho (8) parámetros: `sSQL = "{call REGISTRARVENTA3(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";`.

Comment: wchiquito pero sí le introduzco los 8 parámetros, ya que mi IdOperacion yo lo he puesto para sea consecutivo autoincrement. Y es por eso que no entiendo el por qué del problema.

Comment: El problema no es el procedimiento almacenado, el problema se encuentra al intentar ejecutar `pst.executeUpdate();`.

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutar tu SP directamente en el SQL? Para corroborar que el SP está funcionando correctamente, ya que parece indicar que el problema es en el SQL.

Comment: por eso no entiendo, qué está fallando al ejecutar el pst.executeUpdater(); por favor apóyame, soy un aprendiz de java.

Comment: M. Gress, sí lo he intentado pero me sale error. No sé en qué estaría fallando si ese fuera el caso. Me podrás apoyar por favor?

Comment: ¿Por qué `sSQL = "{call REGISTRARVENTA3(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";` tiene ocho (8) parámetros (?) si el procedimiento almacenado espera solo siete (7)?, debería eliminar un `?` de `sSQL`.

Comment: cuando hago eso me aparece que espera 8 parámetros y estoy introduciendo 7.

Comment: Intente usar `prepareCall`, ver el siguiente enlace (en inglés): [7.3 Using JDBC CallableStatements to Execute Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html#connector-j-examples-stored-procedure).

Comment: uso prepareCall en vez de call?.. correcto?

Comment: Intente cambiar `PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);` por `CallableStatement cst = cn.prepareCall(sSQL);` y `pst.executeUpdate();` por `cst.execute();`.

Comment: Hola, ahora me sale en una ventana el siguiente error: java.SQL.Exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: El nuevo mensaje de error sí parece del procedimiento almacenado. ¿Puede actualizar su pregunta con la estructura de la tabla `operacion`?, ¿cuántas columnas tiene dicha tabla (`operacion`)?.

Comment: hola @wchiquito disculpa que no haya respondido. estuve sin internet. ya edité la pregunta y puse la estructura de la tabla operación. espero aún puedas apoyarme, sigo sin resolver el problema. Gracias.

Comment: Trata de agregarle los campos al procedimiento almacenado. Es decir,
`INSERT INTO operacion (id_producto, fecha, cantidad, estado, precio, stock, venta) VALUES (...)`. Y agrega la estructura de la tabla producto, por favor.

Comment: Como recomendación, evite nombrar los parámetros del procedimiento almacenado como nombres de columnas, evitará problemas. Intente: `INSERT INTO operacion VALUES (NULL, id_produc, fecha, cantidad, estado, precio, stock, venta);` o `INSERT INTO operacion (id_producto, fecha, cantidad, estado, precio, stock, venta) VALUES (id_produc, fecha, cantidad, estado, precio, stock, venta);`

Comment: @MillerAndrésTrujilloAchury gracias por responder, intentaré como dices. ya agregué la tabla producto. espero tus comentarios. gracias

Comment: @wchiquito intentaré tal como indicas. gracias

Comment: Hola chicos, me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, en qué me estoy equivocando?

Comment: @FrankGastelo, Actualiza la pregunta con el código y el procedimiento actual Por favor

Comment: Hola @MillerAndrésTrujilloAchury ya actualicé la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta el query o sql en Mysql Workbench directamente o en phpMyAdmin, te comento directo cual es el error:

Te esta pidiendo no el parámetro ocho de tu tabla actual, sino el que parámetro donde colocas la cadena de texto, es decir, en el parámetro Mensaje. Recuerda que al hacer la llamada o CALL, entonces tienes que pasarle un número de parámetros que son iguales a los de tu tabla actual, como MENSAJE es una variable de salida no tiene un valor definido, su estructura debe ser la siguiente:

SQL:

```
CALL REGISTRARVENTAS(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@MENSAJE);
```

Sustituye al ejecutar al query esos signos con los valores que correspondan.